# NSArray compontentsSeperatedByString returns unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a string containing three words, seperated by a pipeline ( | )
I want to break these up into three separate strings

```
NSArray *bits = [word.variants componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];

NSLog(@"BITS: %@", bits);
```

This returns an unrecognized selector. I use this line of code in other areas in my project, and it works fine. But not on this one.

```
-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6dbfa80
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's likely because `word.variants` isn't a `NSString`. Sure about it ?

Comment: This cannot return an unrecognized selector. It could lead to an exception with that name. What is the exact exception?

Comment: added the exception in my post

Comment: `word.variants` is already an NSArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give us the whole error message, but my bet: You are overreleasing either word or variants and therefor the message is received by another object, that doesn't have the method mentioned in the selector. Try `NSZombieEnbled`. You will find enough post about it on StackOverflow.

*edit*
The error posted by you fits to my assumption. The only other explanation: `variants` is a NSArray.

Comment: in fact, it was actually an array. I redid it now, and it works. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `variants` is an NSArray - `__NSArrayI`mmutable

Answer (score 2):

I have also same problem while my string having so many white character , new line character so i cant do anything but finally i got solution as per following:

```
 NSString *artwork = [currentURL valueForKey:@"artwork_large"]; 
     //i got the string artwork ,which is fetch from json.

[smg addObject:artwork];   
     // add this string to 0th index of an array name:smg


NSSet *setObj1 = [NSSet setWithArray:smg];
      //make the nsset for my array (named :smg)

NSString *pictureName = [[setObj1 allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
      //make the string from all the sets joined by ","


picArray = [pictureName componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
      //now its time for normal operation means makes the array (name: picArray) from string by componenet separatedbystring method
```

this way now i got the perfect array which is in our control

Answer (score 0):

Make it as following, assuming `variants` as NSString

```
NSString *lvariant = word.variants;
NSArray *bits = [lvariant componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
```

Comment: assigning an object to another pointer should not change anything.

Comment: Are you sure `word.variants` returns `NSString`?

Comment: This is good code. You can look in the debugger to see what is actually going on (i.e. that variants is not a string). Only takes a minute. This technique is useful. We are not as smart as we think!

Comment: Then it must be pointed out as debugging technique, not as a solution.